# Formatting datetime values returned in a SELECT..FOR XML statement

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, for-xml

Consider the following table:

**Orders**

```
OrderId             Date               CustomerId
 1000       2012-06-05 20:03:12.000         51
 1001       2012-06-16 12:02:31.170         48  
 1002       2012-06-18 19:45:16.000         33
```

When I extract the Order data using FOR XML:

```
SELECT 
    OrderId AS 'Order/@Order-Id', 
    Date AS 'Order/ShipDate', 
    CustomerId AS 'Order/Customer' 
FROM Orders  
WHERE OrderId = 1000
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

I get the following result:

```
<Order Order-Id="1000">
  <ShipDate>2010-02-20T16:03:12</ShipDate>
  <Customer>51</Customer>
</Order>
```

The problem is, the `ShipDate` value in the XML file needs to be in the format `M/DD/YYYY H:mm:ss PM`. How can I change the output of the `ShipDate` in the XML file to the desired format?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why need to be that format? what do need that format? the one that you get is "the universal one"

Comment: @LuisSiquot Unfortunately, it's a requirement from the customer.  Apparently it's for an integration with an older system.  Thanks for the comment!

Comment: there was here and now deleted a good aproach: use convert() funcion on the select statment, of course it will be a string output but perhaps it works for you. I can retype it if you do not figure how it was

Comment: You'll have to do a `CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), ShipDate, xxxx)` and pick [one of the defined and supported styles for `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187928.aspx) in place of `xxxx`. If you can't use any one of those, you'll probably have to write some ugly string manipulation code (possibly hide it in a user-defined function) to handle this.

Comment: @LuisSiquot Thanks!  I'm thinking I'll need something like: CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 101)

Comment: @marc_s That link is EXACTLY what I needed.  Much appreciated!

Comment: 120 was shown here in the deleted anwser. please check which is fine to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to Andomar's solution, but this provides the requested `h:mm:ss PM` format for the time:

```
DECLARE @o TABLE(OrderId INT, [Date] DATETIME, CustomerId INT);

INSERT @o SELECT 1000,'2012-06-05 20:03:12',51
UNION ALL SELECT 1001,'2012-06-16 12:02:31',48  
UNION ALL SELECT 1002,'2012-06-18 19:45:16',33;

SELECT 
    OrderId AS 'Order/@Order-Id', 
    CONVERT(CHAR(10), [Date], 101) 
    + ' ' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), [Date], 22), 11))
    AS 'Order/ShipDate', 
    CustomerId AS 'Order/Customer' 
FROM @o --WHERE OrderId = 1000
FOR XML PATH ('');
```

Results:

```xml
<Order Order-Id="1000">
  <ShipDate>06/05/2012 8:03:12 PM</ShipDate>
  <Customer>51</Customer>
</Order>
<Order Order-Id="1001">
  <ShipDate>06/16/2012 12:02:31 PM</ShipDate>
  <Customer>48</Customer>
</Order>
<Order Order-Id="1002">
  <ShipDate>06/18/2012 7:45:16 PM</ShipDate>
  <Customer>33</Customer>
</Order>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can use [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to format a date like `mm-dd-yyyy hh:mmAM`:

```
select  convert(varchar(19), OrderDate, 110) + ' ' +
        substring(convert(varchar(19), OrderDate, 100),13,8) AS 'Order/ShipDate'
from    (
        select cast('2012-06-01 01:00' as datetime) as OrderDate
        union all select cast('2012-06-01 14:00' as datetime)
        union all select cast('2012-06-11 23:00' as datetime)
        ) Orders
for xml path ('')
```

This prints:

```
<Order>
  <ShipDate>06-01-2012  1:00AM</ShipDate>
</Order>
<Order>
  <ShipDate>06-01-2012  2:00PM</ShipDate>
</Order>
<Order>
  <ShipDate>06-11-2012 11:00PM</ShipDate>
</Order>
```